# 12:00:00 AM converting to 00:00 instead of 00:00:00

Tags: java, time, java-time, seconds, time-format

I'm trying to convert a time from a string to a Local Time. When converting, it is converting any time with :00 as the seconds to the hour and minute only...

```
12:00:00 AM -> 00:00
11:59:00 AM -> 11:59
```

I'm also going to convert 12 hour time to military but I can't correctly do that until it pulls the 12 hour time correctly.

```
LocalTimeStringConverter ltsc = 
        new LocalTimeStringConverter(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ss a"),
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ss a"));
LocalTime ltStartTime = (LocalTime) ltsc.fromString("12:00:00 AM");
```

How do I get it to pull the seconds so `12:00:00 AM` converts to `00:00:00`?

Comment: 00:00 and 00:00:00 are the same thing. If you want to *display* a LocalTime in a specific format, use a DateTimeFormatter, with the pattern you want.

Answer (score 2):

try [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
String result = ltStartTime.format(formatter);

System.out.println(result);// 00:00:00
```